# Generate pdf using iTextSharp for different languages

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, html-to-pdf

I have tried different options, but it did not work. The code generated pdf for English but does not work for other languages.

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Create an iTextSharp Document which is an abstraction of a PDF but **NOT** a PDF
                var doc = new Document();
                {
                    // Create a writer that's bound to our PDF abstraction and our stream
                    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
                    {
                        // Open the document for writing
                        doc.Open();

                        string finalHtml = string.Empty;

                        // Read your html by database or file here and store it into finalHtml e.g. a string
                        // XMLWorker also reads from a TextReader and not directly from a string
                        using (var srHtml = new StringReader(sHtmlText))
                        {
                            // Parse the HTML
                            iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                        }                            
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }

                // After all of the PDF "stuff" above is done and closed but **before** we
                // close the MemoryStream, grab all of the active bytes from the stream
                return new PDFFormFillerResult(ms, PDFFormFillerResultType.Success, string.Empty);
                //bytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
```

Comment: What options have you tried? What is failing?

Comment: It's not failing it is giving content which are in English as output and ignoring and other language character

Comment: What error do you get and where is it failing?

Comment: @Kenneth no errors, the file is getting created and other language characters are not rendered.

Comment: Do you mean character sets? This program doesn't distinguish between languages. As long as the characters are the same, nothing is different.

Comment: HTML template contains special characters [other language character], so that should get rendered. Isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92854/discussion-between-ravia-and-kenneth).

Comment: Probably a font issue: if iTextSharp does not have access to a font that contains the glyphs for the characters you're trying to display, it won't be able to create the PDF properly.

Answer (score 0):

Well we had to buy another 3rd party tool which understands UNICODE characters.

Comment: *which understands UNICODE characters* - which iTextSharp also does. Your "answer", by the way, does **not** answer the question. As the question also is yours, you could have added this remark to the question as a post scriptum.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create multi language PDF in English and Japanese. 
The prerequisite for achieving this 
1. To have appropriate Font which supports the languages you are planning to use.
2. Implement IFontProvider interface from iTextSharp and register the multi language font you will be using.

If you follow these 2 steps, you can create multi language PDF.

Code Sample:

```
public class smartUIFontProvider: IFontProvider
    {
      public Font GetFont(string fontname, string encoding, bool embedded, float size, int style, BaseColor color)
        {
            string myFont = @"C:\Tasks\Projects\SampleProject\iTextDemo_PDF\SmartFontUI\SmartFontUI.otf";
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont bfR;
            bfR = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(myFont,
              iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
              iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            iTextSharp.text.BaseColor clrBlack =
               new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0);
            iTextSharp.text.Font fntHead =
              new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfR, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, clrBlack);
            return fntHead;
        }
       public bool IsRegistered(string fontname)
        {
            return true;
        }
    } 

static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            // step 1
            Document document = new Document();
            Byte[] bytes;
            var fileName = "resources\\test_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_hhmm") + ".pdf";
            var testFile = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), fileName);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            // step 2

            using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms))
            {
                document.Open();

                String example_html = @" <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> </head> <body> <h1>Change of Control Application</h1> <br/> <p>Please fill out this form if there are updates to your current organization and its relationship Company has on file with the legal binding entity. Company will review the information and may ask you to provide further information before Company agrees to the requested changes.</p> <br/> <table class='bodyText1LIC general' style='width:700px' id='tblInputForm' > <tr> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='4'>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='tableBody1' colspan='4'> <h3>Licensee Information</h3> </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1SerNo'>1.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC'>Licensee Name&nbsp;</td> <td valign='top' class='txtboxtd'> 字詰めなどの調整をおすすめします </td> <td> &nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='4'>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='tableBody1' colspan='4'> <h3>Licensee Primary Contact Information </h3> </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1SerNo'>2.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC'>Name</td> <td class='txtboxtd'> めなどの調整 </td> <td> &nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1SerNo'>3.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC'>Job Title</td> <td class='txtboxtd'> T</td> <td> &nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1SerNo'>4.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC'>Mailing Address</td> <td class='txtboxtd'>めなどの調整</td> <td> &nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1SerNo'>5.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC'>Telephone Number&nbsp;</td> <td class='txtboxtd'>T</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1SerNo'>6.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC'>Email Address&nbsp;</td> <td class='txtboxtd'>abc@test.com</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='4'>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='tableBody1' colspan='4'> <h3> Organizational Structure</h3> </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1SerNo'> 7.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='3'> Will your Company's Name Change?&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td></td> <td colspan='3'> Yes</td> </tr> <tr class='nc' id='TrCompanyName'> <td></td> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='2'> a) &nbsp; &nbsp;New company name&nbsp;</td> <td class='txtboxtd'> DSFDASFASDFDSA</td> </tr> <tr class='nc' id='TrEffectiveDate'> <td></td> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='2'> b) &nbsp; &nbsp;Effective Date Company change will take place &nbsp;</td> <td class='txtboxtd'> 04/20/2017</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1SerNo'>8.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='3'>Has your Company been Reincorporated or under gone an Internal Reorganization?&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td></td> <td colspan='3'> No</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='4'>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='tableBody1' colspan='4'> <h3>Assets / Stocks to be Acquired </h3> </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='tableBody1' colspan='4'> <h3>Assets to be Acquired</h3> </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1SerNo'>9.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='3'>Will some or all of your Company’s Assets be Acquired? &nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td></td> <td colspan='3'> No</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='4'>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='tableBody1' colspan='4'> <h3>Stocks to be Acquired </h3> </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1SerNo'>10.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='3'>Will some or all of your Company’s Assets be Acquired? &nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td></td> <td colspan='3'> No</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='4'>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='tableBody1' colspan='4'> <h3> Effects of Change to Licensee</h3> </td> </tr> <tr> <td  class='bodyText1SerNo'> 11.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='3'> Please indicate which Company is the Surviving Legal Entity? &nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td></td> <td class='txtboxtd' colspan='3'> T</td> </tr> <tr> <td  class='bodyText1SerNo'>12.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='3'>Please provide the Company that will be the Licensee?&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='txtboxtd'>&nbsp;</td> <td colspan='3'> T</td> </tr> <tr> <td valign='top' class='bodyText1SerNo'>13.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='3'>Will any companies exist to operate as separate Subsidiaries or Affiliates ?  &nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td></td> <td colspan='3'> No</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='4'>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='tableBody1' colspan='4'> <h3>Existing Agreements</h3> </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1SerNo'>14.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='3'>Please identify if any Licenses that will be affected by the Changes described above &nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td></td> <td colspan='3'> No</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='4'>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td class='tableBody1' colspan='4'> <h3>Corporate Documentation</h3> </td> </tr> <tr> <td valign='top' class='bodyText1SerNo'>15.</td> <td class='bodyText1LIC' colspan='3'>Please Select from 1 of the 2 options listed below</td> </tr> <tr> <td></td> <td colspan='3'> Please Describe the Full Legal Structure of this Organization Change in relation to Licensing.</td> </tr> <tr> <td></td> <td colspan='3'> ASDFSDAFDSAFADSFDASF &nbsp;</td> </tr> </table> </body> </html>";
                String example_css = @"html { font-family: SmartFontUI; font-size: 14px; }  h1, h2, strong { font-family: SmartFontUI; font-weight: bold; display: inline; }  h1 { font-size: 18pt; }   .main { font-size: 12pt; color: black; font-family: SmartFontUI, Arial, Sans-Serif; background-color: white; text-align: left; line-height: 1.4em; margin: 2%; } .mainDesc { width: 100%; margin: 10px 0; }  span { float: left; display: block; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 5px; }  .bodyText1SerNo { width: 2em; }  .bodyText1LIC { width: 22em; }  .txtboxspan { width: 32em; }  .tableBody1 { width: 100%; } .nc { margin-left: 100px; } .subtitle { font-size: 16pt; }";
                FontFactory.Register(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "SmartFontUI.otf"), "SmartFontUI");

                XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();

                MemoryStream msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_html));
                MemoryStream msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_css));

                smartUIFontProvider smartUIFontObj = new smartUIFontProvider();

                worker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, msHtml, msCss, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, smartUIFontObj);
                // step 5
                document.Close();

            }

            bytes = ms.ToArray();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(testFile, bytes);
        }
```